# clCreateKernel OpenCL call is returning CL_INVALID_PROGRAM_EXECUTABLE

Tags: opencl

I am working with Qualcomm MDP MSM8960 which has support of openCL version 1.1.
I am getting error "CL_INVALID_PROGRAM_EXECUTABLE" when I call "clCreateKernel" function.
Before calling clCreateKernel, "clBuildProgram" function is called and it is returning successfully. Even the "clGetProgramBuildInfo" function which Returns build information for each device in the program object is successful.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You should provide bit more info. How exactly you are calling the functions all the way from creating the context.

Comment: Yes.. The call graph goes like this. clGetPlatformInfo -> clCreateContextFromType -> clGetContextInfo -> clCreateCommandQueue   ->clCreateProgramWithSource -> clBuildProgram -> clCreateKernel. All other functions called returned successfully including clBuildProgram API. But clCreateKernel is failing with the mentioned error. Also verified CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG by calling clGetProgramBuildInfo but it is returning success without giving any info.

Comment: Can you show the source code?